# How to identify the source of a NoReverseMatch error in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I am learning the django framework and want to create a webstore where User's who are designated as 'artists' can post to the webstore.

**To avoid confusion** thcWebsite is the PROJECT NAME. thcStore is an APP in the project!

I am receiving the following error when trying to load localhost:8000/thcStore/

```
NoReverseMatch at /thcStore/
Reverse for 'product_detail' with arguments '(8, '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['thcStore/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/thcStore/
Django Version: 2.2.2
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'product_detail' with arguments '(8, '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['thcStore/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']
Exception Location: C:\Users\TAHAAR~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 668
```

### the following is the error Traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/thcStore/

Django Version: 2.2.2
Python Version: 3.7.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'bootstrap3',
 'cart.apps.CartConfig',
 'orders.apps.OrdersConfig',
 'accounts',
 'payment.apps.PaymentConfig',
 'thcStore']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template C:\Users\Taha Arif\Desktop\Web Development\Personal Website\django_THC\thcWebsite\templates\base.html, error at line 51
   Reverse for 'product_detail' with arguments '(8, '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['thcStore/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']
   41 :               <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
   42 :                   <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'accounts:user_profile' user.display_name %}">Profile</a>
   43 :                   <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a>
   44 :                   <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'accounts:thanks' %}">Logout</a>
   45 :               </div>
   46 :             {% else %}
   47 :             <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
   48 :                 <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a>
   49 :                 <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'accounts:thanks' %}">Logout</a>
   50 :                 <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
   51 :                 <a class="dropdown-item" hr ef="#">Why make an account?</a >
   52 :             </div>
   53 :             {% endif %}
   54 :           {% else %}
   55 :             <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
   56 :                 <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'accounts:signup' %}">Register</a>
   57 :                 <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'accounts:login' %}">Login</a>
   58 :                 <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
   59 :                 <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Why make an account?</a>
   60 :             </div>
   61 :           {% endif %}


Traceback:

File "C:\Users\TAHAAR~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\TAHAAR~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\TAHAAR~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Taha Arif\Desktop\Web Development\Personal Website\django_THC\thcWebsite\thcStore\views.py" in product_list
  22.                    'products': products,},)

File "C:\Users\TAHAAR~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
  36.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "C:\Users\TAHAAR~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
  62.     return template.render(context, request)

File "C:\Users\TAHAAR~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "C:\Users\TAHAAR~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  171.                     return self._render(context)

File "C:\Users\TAHAAR~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\TAHAAR~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\TAHAAR~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\TAHAAR~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  150.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\Users\TAHAAR~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\TAHAAR~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\TAHAAR~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\TAHAAR~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  150.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\Users\TAHAAR~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\TAHAAR~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\TAHAAR~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\TAHAAR~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  62.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\TAHAAR~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\TAHAAR~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\TAHAAR~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  62.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\TAHAAR~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\TAHAAR~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\TAHAAR~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  209.                     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))

File "C:\Users\TAHAAR~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\TAHAAR~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  987.             output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)

File "C:\Users\TAHAAR~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in resolve
  671.                 obj = self.var.resolve(context)

File "C:\Users\TAHAAR~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in resolve
  796.             value = self._resolve_lookup(context)

File "C:\Users\TAHAAR~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  858.                             current = current()

File "C:\Users\Taha Arif\Desktop\Web Development\Personal Website\django_THC\thcWebsite\thcStore\models.py" in get_absolute_url
  55.                        args=[self.id, self.slug])

File "C:\Users\TAHAAR~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py" in reverse
  90.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))

File "C:\Users\TAHAAR~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  668.         raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /thcStore/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'product_detail' with arguments '(8, '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['thcStore/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']
```

This is very confusing to me, because navigating to localhost:8000/thcStore should be calling  *product_list* view. Not sure what about the product_detail view is causing the issue.

First seeing the error, I thought it was an issue I had in my base.html file. 
But as I removed things and cleaned up the code, I found that the error was always caught on line 51. This leads me to believe the issue is not with my base.html file, I am not sure where else to check.

views.py for thcStore

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Category, Product
from  cart.forms import CartAddProductForm
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from .forms import ProductCreateForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

def product_list(request, category_slug=None):
# Catalog View
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)

    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        products = products.filter(category=category)

    return render(request,
                  'thcStore/product/list.html',
                  {'category': category,
                   'categories': categories,
                   'products': products,},)

def product_detail(request, id, slug):
#product View
    product = get_object_or_404(Product,
                                id=id,
                                slug=slug,
                                available=True)
    cart_product_form = CartAddProductForm()
    return render(request, 'thcStore/product/detail.html',
              {'product': product,
               'cart_product_form': cart_product_form})

class product_create(CreateView):
        # form_class = forms.ProductCreateForm
        form_class = ProductCreateForm
        success_url = reverse_lazy("login")
        template_name = "thcStore/product/create.html"
```

urls.py for thcStore

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'thcStore'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.product_list, name='product_list'),
    path('product_create/', views.product_create.as_view(), name='product_create'),
    path('<slug:category_slug>/', views.product_list, name='product_list_by_category'),
    path('<int:id>/<slug:slug>/', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),

]
```

models.py for thcStore

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.text import slugify

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,
                            db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200,
                            unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('thcStore:product_list_by_category',
                       args=[self.slug])

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,
                                 related_name='products',
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d',
                              blank=True)
    owner= models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index= True, default= '')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    # slug= slugify(name)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'),)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            # Newly created object, so set slug
            self.s = slugify(self.q)

        super(Test, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('thcStore:product_detail',
                       args=[self.id, self.slug])
```

I expect that I should be able to load the product_list view when localhost:8000/thcStore/ is called.

Could use your troubleshooting tips, or thought provoking questions.

**EDIT: PROBLEM SOLVED**

I had a product without a slug that was causing the error. Deleting that product fixed the problem.

Comment: The error traceback tells you that the error is caused by `base.html`, line 51.  That line appears to have malformed html `hr ef="#"`.  Perhaps the embedded space is causing the issue?

Comment: thanks for the comment. That space is not in the code, it must have been an error when copying over to stack overflow

Comment: template errors are usually not very well traced in Django. But the error itself is clear: Somewhere you're reversing the 'product_detail' url pattern. Since you're displaying a product list, you're probably linking to the product detail page in your product list. Do you have `{% url 'product_detail' ... %}` in your **list.html** template? Check the arguments you pass to the `{% url %}` tag.

Answer (score 2):

The error is telling you that in the process of rendering the product_list page, it's being asked to generate a link to the product_detail page for product 8 - presumably, your list page links to the detail pages, as you would expect.

It also tells you that in generating that link it's calling the product `get_absolute_url` method. That method uses `reverse` to find the URL for that product given the id and slug. Unfortunately, the slug for product 8 is *an empty string*, so it can't generate a URL for that product that matches the URL pattern (which expects an non empty slug).

You should fix the slug for that product (and maybe others) via the admin, then investigate how it was saved with an empty slug; i'd point out that that `save` method looks dodgy (what is `self.q`?)

Comment: THANKS, yeah I checked and deleted the only product with an empty slug. and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

When looking at error traces, always look for lines that contain your files rather than package files. That's not always the case (especially not with error in templates) but in your case, there are two error lines in your own code:

```
File "C:\Users\Taha Arif\Desktop\Web Development\Personal Website\django_THC\thcWebsite\thcStore\views.py" in product_list
  22.                    'products': products,},)
.
.
.
File "C:\Users\Taha Arif\Desktop\Web Development\Personal Website\django_THC\thcWebsite\thcStore\models.py" in get_absolute_url
  55.                        args=[self.id, self.slug])
```

The most bottom one is always the actual culprit. The first one points to your call to `render()` which triggers the template rendering chain. Inside your template, you have probably a `{% url product %}` which calls the `Product`'s `get_absolute_url()`.

As you can see the error tells you that it's calling `reverse` for "product_detail" with arguments `'(8, '')'`, meaning `self.slug` was the empty string for that particular product.

You should check your `Product.save()` method which I think attempts to create a slug for each product but doesn't. What's `self.s` and what is `self.q`?

Comment: Still getting a NoReverseMatch error

NoReverseMatch at /thcStore/
Reverse for 'product_detail' with keyword arguments '{'id': 8, 'slug': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['thcStore/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']

@dirkgroten, do you think that it is requiring a slug argument for each product?

Comment: apparently product with id 8 does not have a slug (empty string). Check your `save()` method, `self.s = slugify(self.q)` makes no sense, what's `self.q` and what's `self.s`?

Comment: turns out that an empty slug for a product throws that error.

Comment: As I mentioned in my previous comment.